# I'd like to write a Eisbach method with the same functionality of the following Ltac in Coq

Tags: isabelle, coq-tactic

I don't know how to evaluate a term using user-defined functions as part of a Eisbach method code, neither how to do match with a term. The following is a (simplified) defintion of a Coq Ltac, which I would like to write as a Eisbach method in Isabelle/HOL:

```
fun f:: 'a => 'a list := .....

Ltac apply_R :=
match goal with
|  |- ( ... H ...) => let L := eval cbv in f(H)
                      in match L with
                       | nil => apply R; simpl; intuition
                       | _ =>  idtac
                       end
end.
```